# Apache SSL passphrase with p12 file

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

We have a p12 (PKCS#12) **<my_ssl_key_file.p12>** file for SSL Certificate Key file requiring a passphrase. However, referencing it in the apache directive like so does not work:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    ...
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/my_ssl_key_file.p12
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I can get around by converting the p12 file using openssl pkcs12 with the passphrase like so:

```
$openssl pkcs12 -in my_ssl_key_file.p12 -out my_ssl_key_file.key
```

and changing the directive to reference the new **my_ssl_key_file.key**

but this seems counterintuitive to strip the P12 encryption. Is there a way to directly reference the P12 file instead? Perhaps my approach is the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1):

PKCS12 is not supported by SSLCertificateKeyFile.

From the doc, PEM is the required format. And the private key should be protected by a passphrase.

Note that the PKCS12 is used to hold the certificate and the certificate chain and the private key as well.

Comment: That clears it up for me. So I should indeed just extract the PEM certificate from PKCS12 and use that instead?

Comment: extract the private key for the certificate and ensure that it is protected by a password.